# insufficient GL support

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, ogre, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo.
When i'm trying to launch gazebo empty_world this error appears:

```
Insufficient GL support
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 13871, exit code -11].
log files: /home/listov/.ros/log/733761ce-f83a-11e1-9641-e83935533c12/gazebo-1*.log                                                               
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
```

Also there is similar problem with rviz:

```
[ INFO] [1346947909.751136360]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1346947909.751191239]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.3
[ INFO] [1346947909.751208547]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1346947909.843687341]: Loading general config from [/home/listov/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1346947909.843806595]: Loading display config from [/home/listov/.rviz/display_config]
[ INFO] [1346947909.916929322]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
[ERROR] [1346947909.921440824]: Caught exception while loading: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unexpected failure to determine a GLXFBConfig in GLXWindow::create at /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-visualization-common-1.6.3/debian/ros-electric-visualization-common/opt/ros/electric/stacks/visualization_common/ogre/build/ogre_src_v1-7-3/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 302)
```

My configuration:
Video card: nVIDIA GeForce GT520
Driver: LINUX X64 (AMD64/EM64T) DISPLAY DRIVER version 304.43
OS: Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit
ROS: electric

I saw the similar problem with [Fedora](http://answers.ros.org/question/28859/gazebo-insufficient-gl-support/) but i'm not sure it'll help me (i'm quite new with Linux).

So i'll appreciate any help. thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43263/insufficient-gl-support/) by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 338 on 2012-09-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-07**:
Have you tried the solutions in this answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/28859/gazebo-insufficient-gl-support/ ?

**Comment by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on 2012-09-07**:
No, i'm now trying to configure nvidia driver. I have these error when call glxgears:    couldn't get   an RGB, Double-buffered visual.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-09-07**:
I'd suggest going over to this site for help until you can get glxgears working, then come back here if you still have problems with ROS stuff: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-09-07**:
I'd suggest trying the nvidia drivers: http://www.linoob.com/2011/04/installing-hardware-drivers-in-ubuntu/

**Comment by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on 2012-09-07**:
Everything is fine now, i've reinstalled this driver. When I was doing it first time, I  accidentally chose support of openGL 32 bit libraries.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-07**:
Please go ahead and answer your question (in the box below). That way others with similar problems can easily find your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everything is fine now, i've reinstalled this driver. When I was doing it first time, I accidentally chose support of openGL 32 bit libraries.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) with karma: 338 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3